# Usage of abstract class in the builder pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, fluent, builder-pattern

I have two types of payload coming from upstream: It's either `PayloadA` or `PayloadB`. There are some common fields between `PayloadA` and `PayloadB` so I created `Payload` class with those common fields and for rest I created two builder class one for each payload.

Below is the builder class for `PayloadA`:

```
public final class PayloadA {
  private final String clientId;
  private final String langid;
  private final String deviceId;
  private final Map<String, String> applicationPayload;

  private PayloadA(Builder builder) {
    this.clientId = builder.clientId;
    this.langid = builder.langid;
    this.deviceId = builder.deviceId;
    this.applicationPayload = builder.applicationPayload.build();
  }

  public static class Builder {
    protected final String deviceId;
    protected String clientId;
    protected String langid;
    protected ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String> applicationPayload = ImmutableMap.builder();

    public Builder(String deviceId) {
      this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public Builder setClientId(String clientId) {
      this.clientId = clientId;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setLangid(String langid) {
      this.langid = langid;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setPayload(Map<String, String> payload) {
      this.applicationPayload.putAll(payload);
      return this;
    }

    public PayloadA build() {
      return new PayloadA(this);
    }
  }

    // getters and to string here
}
```

Now below is the class for `PayloadB`:

```
public final class PayloadB {
  private final String clientid;
  private final String type;
  private final String payId;

  private PayloadB(Builder builder) {
    this.clientid = builder.clientid;
    this.type = builder.type;
    this.payId = builder.payId;
  }

  public static class Builder {
    protected final String type;
    protected String payId;
    protected String clientid;

    public Builder(String type) {
      this.type = type;
    }

    public Builder setPayId(String payId) {
      this.payId = payId;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder setClientId(String clientid) {
      this.clientid = clientid;
      return this;
    }

    public PayloadB build() {
      return new PayloadB(this);
    }
  }

    // getters and to string here
}
```

Now I have created another class which is `Payload` class (does this have to be abstract class?) in which I have all the common fields both for `PayloadA` and `PayloadB` so I have to set these fields as well somehow and I am not sure how to use below class:

```
public abstract class Payload {
  private long createTimestamp;
  private String partition;
  private String key;
  // some other fields here

  // getters and setters here
}
```

**Question:**

- Now let's say if we get `PayloadB` from upstream, then I want `key` field in the `Payload` class to be whatever is the value of `type` in `PayloadB` class in all lower case and if we get `PayloadA` from upstream, then I want key to be `world`.
- And also if we get `PayloadB` from upstream and if `clientId` was set, then I want `partition` to be `15` and if we get `PayloadA` from upstream and if `clientId` was set then I want `partition` to be `15` but if it was not set and `langId` was there, then I want `partition` to be `17`.
- And I want to set `createTimestamp` as well which I have to do after building a Payload object. So for example I have build PayloadA object and it will be passed to some other class and there I need to set createTimestamp value on PayloadA object. Not sure how to do that as well? Do I have to clone something?

How can I use `Payload` class in my builder pattern? I will get two different payloads and there will be few things common in them so common fields I have separated them out in an abstract class.

Should I have on big builder pattern class with everything in it or multiple builder pattern extending something?

Comment: To begin, why are you using builders ? It looks like the code is over-engineered...

Comment: In general all these Payload have lot of fields. To make example simpler to understand I made it like that.

Comment: Ok, so you introduced builders because of huge classes. Did you already considered refactoring in smaller classes, thus resolving the *root* of the problem ? At the moment your problem sounds to me like an [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/): you ask how to use an abstract class in a builder (which is something very uncommon) instead of asking yourself "why do I ended up in such a strange construct ?"

Comment: hmmm then how should I approach this problem?

Comment: For which purpose do you need `PayloadX` ? Are they DTO or BO ? Do they actually contain some business logic or is it only a bunch of getters ? Is it realistic that you post the full code (at least all the attributes) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I won't pass `builder` instance to the `PayloadX` constructor. Either pass values as individual constructor arguments or call setters.
- You can define `Payload.Builder` which would hold common fields of `PayloadA` and `PayloadB`. This class will be an abstract class declaring an abstract `build` method.
- `PayloadA.Builder` and `PayloadB.Builder` will extend `Payload.Builder`, implementing the `build` method.
- In this `build` method you implement whatever custom logic you need to create and set the fields of the `PayloadX`.

It seems like you want to make your class immutable (careful with `applicationPayload` by the way). In this case you can't really "set" anything. You can only produce a new instance. There are many ways to do this, for instance you can implement `PayloadX withTimestamp(...)` method. Or you can extend your build to accept `PayloadX` and set timestamp there, resulting in something like `new PayloadX.Builder(payloadXInstance).setTimestamp(...).build()`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of all your above suggestions? It will help me to understand better. As of now I am confuse how to use your suggestion.

Comment: @david I will not, sorry, this exceeds the amount of time I am ready to contribute.